# How can i Create/Open projects in new tab?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whenever i try to work in two different projects,i have to close one of them How can i **Create**/**Open** new projects in a new tab without closing current project or solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to operate several projects at the same time is just to open another Visual-studio window by clicking on Visual Studio again. Then you can open a new project without closing the previous one. You can then switch between them with `alt-tab` keys or see them both by tiling the two windows.

That's what I do anyway.